# Find the smallest prime positive integer in each of the following.

Tags: prime-numbers

> 1. Find the smallest positive integer such that $80-n$ and $80+n$ are prime numbers.
> 2. Find the smallest positive prime number such that $2002-n$ and $2002+n$ are prime numbers.

I cannot think of any way other than trying the prime numbers one by one, 
like trying from $2, 3, 5, 7,\ldots...$ but it will probably take forever in case the answer is a big number, any clue please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How great! But is there a more reasoned approach to this problem?

Comment: Note that the square root of $2000$ is less than $45$ ($45^2=2025$), so $43$ is the greatest prime you have to test so far as divisibility is concerned for $2002-n$.

Answer (score 3):

For the first.

1) $n$ is not of the form $3k+1$ otherwise $80+n$ is divisible by $3$.

2) $n$ is not of the form $3k+2$ otherwise $80-n$ is divisible by $3$.

3)**So n is a multiple of** $3$.

4) $n$ can not have factors $2, 5$. In particular $n$ is odd. **So n is an odd multiple of** $3$ that is not divisible by $5$.

Examining odd multiples (not divisible by $5$ ) of $3$ is easy. $n=9$ is the answer.

Comment: I get your point there, but it still involves trials by substituting k=1,2,3... Especially for the second one, to my knowledge, the answer is quite big, so if this strategy is kept it would still take some time. Is there a more general approach? Or are prime number questions have to be simply done this way?:(

Comment: Please read the answer again.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I fully understood how you got to the answer, but we cannot use this approach for the second question, can we?

Comment: @Jacky You're welcome. Why not? For the second one a similar reasoning can be applied.

Comment: As far as I know, the answer to the second question is 1999, which is a prime number.. multiple won't work will it?

Comment: n=1999?How do you find it?

Comment: Yes n=1999 for Q2, it's in the model answer, but I am rather interested in the steps achieving it.

Comment: For the first step factorize 2002. $2002=2\times 7\times 11\times 13$

Comment: I can only conclude p is not 2,7,11,13 from that, is there anymore insights?

Answer (score 2):

For question 2, note that the question asks for a prime number n, unlike question 1. The same reasoning applies as in [Fermat](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83272/fermat)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1181141/206402) in terms of mod 3 analysis:

$2002 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, therefore

- for $n \equiv 1 \bmod 3,$ we have $2002-n \equiv 0 \bmod 3$  (only prime if $2002-n=3$)
- for $n \equiv 2 \bmod 3,$ we have $ 2002+n \equiv 0 \bmod 3$  (never prime)
- for $n \equiv 0 \bmod 3,$ we have $ 2002\pm n \equiv 1 \bmod 3$  (only $n=3$ is prime)

We can only possibly have primes for these for the cases where either $n=3$ or $2002-n=3$. In either case, if $2002-3=1999$ were not prime, there would definitely be no solutions - but it is. So we can check just the two cases, $n=3$ and $n=1999$. $2005$ is not a prime, but $4001$ is, giving the only solution of $n=1999$.